# Where to find medical related data?

Tags: nlp, medical, images, biology, disease

I am wondering where to retrieve medical related data, particularly those related to Tropical Medicine? It would be wonderful if anyone can suggest where to find these:

1. A collection (I mean thousands if not hundred of thousands) of parasite and parasite ova images.
2. Medical corpus related to medical parasitology or medical microbiology focusing on Infectious Tropical Diseases.

Answer (score 2):

As I already answered on a later question, a list of Medical Imaging *datasets* can be found on the [`medical-imaging-datasets`](https://github.com/sfikas/medical-imaging-datasets) repository. Also, it could be interesting to follow both [Stephen R. Aylward's](http://www.aylward.org/notes/open-access-medical-image-repositories) list of repositories and the [SICAS Medical Image Repository](https://www.smir.ch/).